# Gibbs energy calculations for compounds

Tags: energy, resource-recommendations, quantum-chemistry, density-functional-theory, chemical-compounds

I am studying machine learning during my master's degree and have a simple task. I am using the FactSage Pure Substance Database (https://www.crct.polymtl.ca), which provides a list of phases for a system of elements and for each phase (e.g., S1 - the first solid phase of the C system) the standard Gibbs energy of formation, enthalpy, and entropy are specified for each temperature. I use basic machine learning methods to predict Gibbs energy for different phases based on the given composition of the substance. Of course, there are some questions regarding the addressing and order of phases, but that's not what I'm asking about. I would like to ask for advice on what literature and articles to study on calculating Gibbs energy ab initio or using highly universal numerical methods to apply this knowledge to a deeper extension of the machine learning model. I am not a physicist by education, but familiar with the basics of quantum physics, however, I have never dealt with Gibbs energy calculations and quantum chemistry. I understand that my question is silly, but please, if it's not too much trouble, advise what to study and read about calculating the Gibbs energy of various substances.

Comment: What is "Translate to English" at the start here supposed to mean? If you machine-translated this text from another language, you should a) mention the translation tool used and b) clearly state that this is what happened.

Comment: sorry, I'll fix that. yes, it's translated to english